# how to get automatically new JWT Token and Refresh Token in angular

Tags: c#, angular, jwt, refresh-token

I am using angular and asp.net core I have implemented JWT Token and refresh token with the help of
[this artical](https://code-maze.com/using-refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-authentication/) I have written code to check Jwt is valid in Authguard if jwt is not valid so with refresh token will make  call to api and get the new Jwt and refresh token . this scenario is happing only if I am performing any event like refreshing page and navigating to another page. **I want to know is there any way that if our jwt token expire without performing any event angular detect it and automatically call to api with refersh token and get the new jwt token**

here are codes

**authguard**

here in authguard  isUserAuthenticated() is going to check jwt expired or not if expired it will make api call with refresh token  and get the new jwt and refresh token

```
async canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    if((await this._authService.isUserAuthenticated()) === true){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      this._router.navigate([RouteConstant.SIGN_IN]);
      return false;
    }
  }

public async isUserAuthenticated(){
    if(this._storageService.getToken() !== null){
      if(!this._jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(this._storageService.getToken()?.toString())){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        if(!this._storageService.refreshTokenExists()){
          return false;
        }
        else{
          let authTokenClient: AuthTokenClient = {
            token: this._storageService.getToken() as string,
            refreshToken: this._storageService.getRefreshToken() as string
          };
          let response: AuthToken = await this._serverService.refreshAuthToken(authTokenClient).toPromise<AuthToken>();
          console.log(response);
          this.setAuth(response);
          return !this._jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(this._storageService.getToken()?.toString());
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  }

  public setAuth(authToken: AuthToken){
    this._storageService.saveToken(authToken.token?.toString());
    this._storageService.saveRefreshToken(authToken.refreshToken);
  }
  public async refreshAuthToken(authTokenClient: AuthTokenClient) {
    const response = await this._http.post<AuthToken>(environment.apiHost + UrlConstant.ACCOUNT_REFRESH, authTokenClient,{observe: 'response'}).toPromise();
    console.log(response);
    const newToken = (<any>response).body.token;
            console.log(newToken);
            const newRefreshToken = (<any>response).body.refreshToken;
            console.log(newRefreshToken);
            localStorage.setItem("token", newToken);
            localStorage.setItem("refreshToken",newRefreshToken);
            if (newToken && newRefreshToken == null){
              return false
            }
            else {
              return true;
            }
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                    ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidIssuer,
                    ValidAudience = jwtSettings.ValidAudience,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration[ConfigurationKeyConstant.JWT_SECRET_KEY])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
```

**Controller.cs**

```
[Route("refresh")]
        public IActionResult Refresh(AuthTokenBase authTokenBase)
        {
            if (authTokenBase is null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid client request");
            }
            string accessToken = authTokenBase.Token;
            string refreshToken = authTokenBase.RefreshToken;
            var principal = this._jwtHandler.GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(accessToken);
            var username = principal.Identity.Name; 
            string newAccessToken = this._jwtHandler.GenerateToken(); 
            string newRefreshToken = this._jwtHandler.GenerateRefreshToken();
            return Ok(new AuthToken()
            {
                Token = newAccessToken,
                RefreshToken = newRefreshToken,
                IsAuthSuccessful = true
            });
        }
```

Comment: We use a timer observable to refresh before the token expires, but it gets complicated when there are calls going out during the refresh. Why do you want to do this? Why isn't the default implementation good?

Comment: @MotKohn as you mention timer observable in went on web and found there is time interval so I use it in my code `import { interval, Observable, Subscription } from "rxjs"; 
timer: any;
 constructor(private _authservice: AuthService, private _storageService: StorageService) { }   
ngOnInit() {     this.timer = interval(60000).subscribe(x => {       this._authservice.isUserAuthenticated();   
  });  ` is this right way ??

Comment: That is what I meant, but again: What are you going to do about calls that are happening while you invalidated the old token and did not yet get back the new one? That is why the authguard is implemented the way it is.

Comment: @MotKohn As I am not setting `ClockSkew=TimeSpan.Zero` in Startup.cs => Configure in asp.net-core  so even after my token will expire server will allow that till 5 minutes which is default `ClockSkew`. As I am keeping my JWT token expiry time for 5 minutes and  keeping time-interval to check validity is 4 minutes .So I think in this way my call will always success

Answer (score 0):

Under your ConfigureServices at `service.AddAuthentication()` you can add **event** for OnAuthenticationFailed.

And there check for exception type if its **SecurityTokenExpiredException**, then set response header ***tokenExpired=true***.

Later at client side check response header and call refresh token API based on tokenExpired value.

pseudo code:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                    ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.ValidIssuer,
                    ValidAudience = jwtSettings.ValidAudience,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration[ConfigurationKeyConstant.JWT_SECRET_KEY])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
                     if (context.Exception.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenExpiredException))
                     {
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("IS-TOKEN-EXPIRED", "true");
                     }
                  return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
  });
```

Here in response header it sets **IS-TOKEN-EXPIRED** as **true**, if token is expired.
For more detail you can check this [Blog article](https://codepedia.info/aspnet-core-jwt-refresh-token-authentication) written by me.

Answer (score -1):

You can use angular interceptor.
Intercept every error in  http request

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        var modifiedRequest = this.normalizeRequestHeaders(request);
        return next.handle(modifiedRequest)
            .pipe(
                catchError(error => {
                    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
                        return this.tryGetRefreshTokenService(request, next, error);
                    } else {
                        return this.handleErrorResponse(error);
                    }
                }),
                switchMap((event) => {
                    return this.handleSuccessResponse(event);
                })
            );
}
```

Comment: Note that link-only answers are strongly discouraged on Stack Overflow and eventually get deleted. The answer should be edited to summarize the link's key points within the answer itself.